# Creating a git diff from nothing

Tags: git, diff, patch, review-board

I am trying to create a patch file to be used via [reviewboard](http://www.reviewboard.org).
It will be the initial patch.

`diff -ruN --exclude=.git empty_dir working_dir > mypatch_00.patch` works but I am getting a "The selected file does not appear to be a diff." error.

Is there any way to get it working using git-diff or diff? Thank you

Comment: What's the content of the diff?  I think the command you're running will just result in a list of file names and not actual diffs.  This is also what you get with `git log -p` which would otherwise work for you.

Comment: @AndrewMyers I'm getting this kind of entries https://gist.github.com/4e98d97a21990c657ac3

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you want to get diff for your initial commit (maybe I misunderstood your question), you can display it using

```
git show COMMIT
```

Alternatively to get it as file:

```
git format-patch -1 COMMIT
```

Where `COMMIT` is revision of this commit. If this is your current commit as well, you don't have to specify it at all.

However if your commit is not initial and you want to get full diff for your history, you need to create empty branch first:

```
git checkout --orphan empty         # Create orphaned branch
git read-tree --empty               # Remove all files from index
git commit --allow-empty -m 'Empty' # Initial commit
```

Now you can do full diff against empty branch:

```
git diff empty..master
```

Comment: I know about `git show` and `git format-patch`. I want to create a diff against nothing, meaning it would be only added lines and my file would be completely green.  
It is what I got from `diff -ruN --exclude=.git empty_dir working_dir > mypatch_00.patch` but reviewboard does not recognize it as a correct diff.

Comment: Ah, I though what you want to get is diff of first revision in Git, sorry for misunderstanding... I've updated the answer to cover this as well.

Comment: Now this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.
edit: seems like I can only award my bounty in 20 hours. You will get it tomorrow then.

Comment: I recommend using `git read-tree --empty` over deleting the index file.

Comment: @RichardHansen Indeed it's cleaner approach, I did not know this command. Updated the answer.

Comment: The result is exactly what I am looking for, but is there a solution involving not manipulating the repo? I would like not to tamper with it. I have looked everywhere and this is the closed.

Answer (score 21):

If you want the full diff from nothing to a particular commit, there is an easier way than in the accepted answer:

```
empty_tree=$(git hash-object -t tree /dev/null) 
git diff-tree -p ${empty_tree} $MY_COMMIT [${files}...]
```

The value of `${empty_tree}` is always `4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904` but I prefer not to have the magic number in there.

Comment: Best answer (:  Also gives a nice searchable keyword for more info (4b825d...).

Answer (score 0):

I prefer "empty" as a tag. Simplest way is:

```
git tag empty $(git hash-object -t tree /dev/null)
```

Because tag can point to tree-ish directly, without commit.
Now to get all files in the working tree:

```
git diff --name-only empty
```

Or the same with stat:

```
git diff --stat empty
```

All files as diff:

```
git diff empty
```

Check whitespaces in all files:

```
git diff --check empty
```